# Running Balance in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have tried the following query to get account transactions

```
select TranRef, TrnDate, AcNumber, AcName, DrCr, amount from Accounts
join Voucher
on Accounts.acid = voucher.accountno
join Transactions
on Transactions.TrnRef = Voucher.TranRef
where acnumber = 1010
```

[image: Result of my query]

but I want the result in following format

[image: the Result which I want]

Comment: "In sql" isn't really a "thing". Every RDBMS uses different syntax; although there are commonalities and ANSI sql that is supported across the lot. YOu tagged 2 different RDBMS here, `sql-server` and `mysql`, which are very different. The image appears it's from SSMS though, which is sQL Server. The  next step for you, however, is editting you post to provide consumable sample data (an image isn't useful, we can't interact with it) and tag the version of SQL Server (which one you're using will change the answer).(http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use *window* function :

```
select TranRef, TrnDate, AcNumber, AcName, DrCr, amount,
       (case when DrCr= 'Dr' then amount else 0 end) as Debit,
       (case when DrCr= 'Cr' then amount else 0 end) as Credit,
       sum(case when DrCr = 'Cr' then amount else -amount end) over (partition by v.accountno order by TranRef) as Balance
from Accounts a
inner join Voucher v on a.acid = v.accountno
inner join Transactions t on t.TrnRef = v.TranRef
where v.accountno = 1010;
```